# how to change table data color if value is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am coding a transaction table which should show debit values in red and credit values in green, but i want this colors to only take effect if table data is greater than 0 using javascript. please help...

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#ccccff">

              <th scope="col">   Debit</th>
              <th scope="col"> Credit</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>

              <td id='red' style="color:red; font-weight: bold;"> 100  </td>
              <td id='green' style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">       
                200
                </td>

            </tr>


          </tbody>
```

Comment: and what have you researched or tried so far? What problem are you facing? This isn't a free write-my-code or do-my-research site, but we will _help_ you with any effort you have made yourself. P.S. How are you populating this table? Assuming you don't intend to hard-code it, then it would make sense for whatever code is populating the table (whether it be server-side code, or JavaScript) to set the colours at the moment it creates / populates the cell.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your html it looks like you are using datatables so you must be using jQuery, Here's how I would do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 3,
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        var color = 'black';
        if (data < 0) {
          color = 'red';
        }
        if (data > 0) {
          color = 'green';
        }
        return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + data + '</span>';
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>-3</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>-61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$4,525</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```